# Spring Boot EnvironmentPostProcessor not loading application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a custom EnvironmentPostProcessor that adds a property to the environment. In order to add this property correctly, I need to know a url, which is dependent on the profile that I am using, url that exists in every application property. Everything worked fine until I added as a dependency a local module, module which uses `spring-cloud-starter-vault-config`. Now the environment does not have the application properties values but has the values of the other module. Please see below a visual representation:

```
myProcessor
 - resources
   -- application.properties
   -- application-dev.properties
newlyAddedModdule/Dependency
 - resources
  -- application.properties
```

How can I make the project load the application.properties and not the other modules propertis?

P.S: I'd prefer a solution where I dont read the application properties files myself but rather have the ConfigurableEnvironment provide these for me, as it did before.

Comment: I suspect your environment post-processor is running in Spring Cloud's bootstrap context. It will then run again in the main application context. You may just be able to ignore the invocation in the bootstrap context. I believe you can identify that invocation by the environment containing a property source named `bootstrap`.

Comment: that is true, I have a bootstrap map, but I dont have the properties that I needed. Moving them in bootstrap is not an option since we are talking about different modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found (and that is working) was to rename my properties files under the following structure:

```
 - application.properties
 - bootstrap-dev.properties
 - bootstrap-prod.properties
```

as I needed properties under a certain profile the profile file will be loaded at the same time with the vault bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to put the right value in the vault. But I guess that not an options.

Another way is to give the properties of the myProcessor a higher priority. See [Spring Externalized Configuration order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

The easiest  way I found is by putting the newlyAddedModule-properties in a jar, and the have myProcessor-properties strait on the classpath.